# Need one login for two or more different sites in joomla

Tags: php, authentication, joomla

I am tasked to create a web site using joomla. It will be a 'sister' site to an existing joomla site. Both are in the same domain.

However, the owners want the users to be able to log into one and still be logged into the other one.

How can this be accomplished? If it is possible

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 1):

Use [OpenID](http://www.joomlaspan.com/general/joomla-openid-and-user-registration.php) instead of local authentication.

Comment: I imagine you install an OpenID login module on both sites. Once this is done, users can login using their OpenID accounts.

Have you used OpenID before? You register at a website such as https://www.myopenid.com/. This account is then connected to each OpenID-enabled website such as Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

It is surely possible -

1. Cookies must be subdomain independent
2. You should sync-up user and session tables across subdomains.

To do task-1, refer http://www.idealog.us/2006/09/php_session_coo.html . For task-2 you can write a plugin, which sync up user and session table across subdomains.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to create two separate sites within the same instance of Joomla...

First, follow the instructions at http://docs.joomla.org/Multiple_Domains_and_Web_Sites_in_a_single_Joomla!_installation which explains how to create the two sites.

When you create your site templates, use different module positions for each of the sites. For example if your menu is normally published in module position "left", you can create the second template with a module position called "left2" and then create separate menus for each site and just publish them to the relevant site's module position.

Hope this helps!

Matt

Answer (score 0):

I use JMS2Win.

http://www.jms2win.com/[JMS2Win](http://www.jms2win.com/)

You can use it to create duplicate sites which share the same DB and different tables within.

It cost about $80, but is well worth the money, as it's a component with fairly good documentation.  The guy who built it, Edwin provides good support too.

I duplicated four sites off one master with different content, with shared user tables.  Realyly elegant, as it's not a sync system, it's shared...